# Express Go To Direct Link In React Router/React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am using React Router 4 for my project, when I directly type the url to the browser like `localhost:8000/post/1` I get the following error.

> Cannot GET /post/1

My code on express server is

```
app.get('/post/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html', {root: __dirname});
})
```

I tried using the `{HashRouter}` package on `react-router-dom` to allow a hash bang but it doesn't seem to work right as well.

How can I fix this error? and allow direct linking in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an application served by node that has routing handled client side like is the case with React and React-router, you will need to serve your index.html to every request.

Put this, ( the `app.get` ) below any API routing in your express application.

```
var path = require('path');

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

This will ensure that every request to your server that is not an API call serves your index.html to your user. Once the client has the index.html, the internal routing will be handled by React-routing.

Comment: I tried that, but that goes to the url like this `http://localhost:8000/post/1#/` what I want instead is `http://localhost:8000/#/post/1`

Comment: Is this application viewed in web browsers? If so you should use BrowserRouter. Then the above should work with direct navigation to `http://localhost/post/1` if you have a react-router designed to handle the route.